# How do I iterate through an object but display then in separate rows?

Tags: javascript, loops, aurelia

What I'm trying to accomplish is iterating through an object, each of the object has a `type` property. The goal is to iterate through each object and display them in a row designated by their `type`.

**Right now it looks like this**
[image]

What I'm trying to do is have the Frontend, Backend, and UI on separate rows.

I'm using **Aurelia Framework**, **here's my View:**

```
<template>
<div class="project-preview-container container">
    <div class="row" repeat.for="projectType of projectTypes">
        <div class="col-md-3 project-preview" repeat.for="project of projects">
            <h3 class="${project.type}">${project.type}</h3>
            <h1>${project.name}</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Here's my Model:**

```
export class Portfolio {

constructor() {
    this.header = "Portfolio";
    this.projectTypes = ["Frontend", "Backend", "UI"];
    this.projects = [
        {
            name: "Project Name 1",
            type: "Frontend",
            img: [
                "Image 1",
                "Image 2",
                "Image 3"
            ],
            descriptionTitle: [
                "Description Title 1",
                "Description Title 2",
                "Description Title 3"
            ],
            description: [
                "Description 1",
                "Description 2",
                "Description 3"
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "Project Name 2",
            type: "Frontend",
            img: [
                "Image 1",
                "Image 2",
                "Image 3"
            ],
            descriptionTitle: [
                "Description Title 1",
                "Description Title 2",
                "Description Title 3"
            ],
            description: [
                "Description 1",
                "Description 2",
                "Description 3"
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "Project Name 3",
            type: "Backend",
            img: [
                "Image 1",
                "Image 2",
                "Image 3"
            ],
            descriptionTitle: [
                "Description Title 1",
                "Description Title 2",
                "Description Title 3"
            ],
            description: [
                "Description 1",
                "Description 2",
                "Description 3"
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "Project Name 4",
            type: "UI",
            img: [
                "Image 1",
                "Image 2",
                "Image 3"
            ],
            descriptionTitle: [
                "Description Title 1",
                "Description Title 2",
                "Description Title 3"
            ],
            description: [
                "Description 1",
                "Description 2",
                "Description 3"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

}

Any and all feedback is accepted, thank you!

Comment: why there are two rows in the picture ?

Comment: To show what I mean let's say you have folders named: Frontend, Backend, UI. Inside each of those folders is supposed to have their respective types but instead what's happening is I'm duplicating the content into each folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just looping through the project types but don't use that data for anything. The inner loop goes through all projects and lists them all, no matter what their type is.

You'll need to either restructure your data so that `projectType` acts as a container for all projects of that type, or add an `if` that checks that the project's type matches `projectType` like this: (pardon me, I've never actually used Aurelia so might not work as-is)

```
<div if.bind="projectType == project.type">
  <h3 class="${project.type}">${project.type}</h3>
  <h1>${project.name}</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Would you recommend doing the former? Instead of having a separate array?

Comment: That's a tougher one and depends on how else you'll be using the data. Semantically project types aren't parents for the projects themselves so I'd probably not restructure if I have any need for either accessing all the projects at once or any of them directly. Moving them under their type would require you to know the type beforehand or iterate through the types until you find the right one.

Comment: Good point, I'll just stick to the if block, I wasn't sure how it worked in Aurelia, still getting used to it, I do appreciate the assistance, back to portfolio building I go.